# .htaccess removal of extensions

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm having some troubles with my .htaccess file, I have code placed in which removes the extensions of files so it looks like this: www.foo.com/x and it works fine for all of my pages. However, when I use my navigation bar it doesn't work. I've already changed the URLs on each page to www.foo.com/x, so I'm confused as to what my problem could be. Here's the code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

And here's my nav-bar code:

```
 <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.foo.com/" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.foo.com/projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.foo.com/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.foo.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I might add that www.foo.com/projects, etc. works fine and goes to the correct page also my .htaccess file is in the root folder if that wasn't obvious.

Comment: What about just `about` or just `contact`? You don't need the full URL if it's on your server, you only need the relative path.

Comment: That still shows the .html extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original rules are going to cause a loop if you try to internally rewrite them back. For example, if you start off with the URI `/some/file.html`

1. Browser requests `/some/file.html`
2. `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]` matches, browser is redirected to `/some/file`
3. Browser requests `/some/file`
4. Internal rewrite to `/some/file.html`
5. Rewrite engine loops, first rule matches again, browser is redirected to `/some/file`
6. repeat from #3

So you need to match against the actual request for your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

This does the redirect, in case you have links that still go to the .html files, now you need to internally rewrite them back to html files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

If all of your links already have the .html part removed, then you won't need the first rule at all.